# UIAutomation on non acccessible elements

Tags: ios, testing, accessibility, instruments, ui-automation

I have a few buttons on my view that have isAccessibilityElement set to NO.

Is there anyway to test these elements via UIAutomation through instruments using jasmine scripts?